# How good is the Leech lattice for AWGN coding or MSE quantization of Gaussian sources?

Tags: gaussian, channelcoding, information-theory, quantization, coding

Anyone know where to find graphs showing how well it works vs other schemes? thanks

Comment: *The Leech Lattice and the Golay Code: Bounded-Distance Decoding and Multilevel Constructions* by Amrani, Be’ery, Vardy, Sun, and van Tilborg has a (bit-error-rate) vs (Eb/No) plot in Figures 11,12 for a Leech lattice codebook in Gaussian noise.  Is there such a plot for *symbol*-error-rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables 7.1 and 7.2 from *Lattice Coding of Signals and Networks* by Zamir are essentially this.

Also the figures in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.0171.pdf